# Obtain short lived access token from dropbox without redirect url(through .net code or javascript)

Tags: amazon-s3, dropbox, access-token, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I am trying to implement a way to obtain a short lived access token from dropbox, then upload multiple file to a folder. and finally revoke the token.
This can obtain access token can be .net code or in javascript. But what I am seeing from the dropbox documentation is having a redirect url which I don't want to redirect anything.

[image]

also I do not need to ask the end user to allow anything, what I need is to get a temp access token and upload some files.

This scenario is doable in Amazon S3 by generating a short lived policy for file upload.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I recommend reading the Dropbox [OAuth Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/lp/developers/reference/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization) for information on the available options. Dropbox also offers short-lived access tokens now. Check out [this post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens) for information on that. Also, when using the 'code' flow, a redirect URI is optional.

Comment: both code flow and PKCE flow need the user to click allow to get through the flow and acquire an access token. what I need is to get the access token on the server, use this token on client side and upload the file. and repeat this each time. there is no need for user interaction. @Greg

Comment: The initial authorization does require manual user interaction, for the user to authorize the app. After that though, the app can store and re-use the access token without further manual user interaction. If you need long-term access (longer than four hours) without the user present, you'll want to request "offline" access. Check out the links in my last comment for information on using that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I totally understand what you saying, I allow the app and I get one access token and a refresh token. But after that if I want to refresh the access token, again I need to go through the same flow in which we need interaction. If I call the RefreshAccessToken it will not give back the new token(s). @Greg

Comment: No, you do not need to process the app authorization flow every time you need a new short-lived access token. You can use the same refresh token to get a new short-lived access token by calling /oauth2/token when needed. The refresh token does not change.

Comment: @Greg thanks, one more question, oauth2/token does not return a new refresh token, can I get a new refresh token programatically?

Comment: No, you cannot get a new refresh token programmatically without sending the user through the app authorization flow again, but you shouldn't need to. You should just continue re-using the same refresh token for a given user whenever you need a new short-lived access token for them.